# Why is my Guild Wars (1) ping so terrible?

Tags: guild-wars

I've been playing Guild Wars 2 for a couple of months and as I really wanted to know more about the lore and what happened before Guild Wars 2, I bought Guild Wars a few days ago. I was really looking forward to playing it, but the ping is so high ingame (much more than 1000ms, always varying) that it's unplayable. I have to wait for about a minute or longer when I want to accept a quest and I get disconnected a lot.

It's definetely not a problem with my internet connection. My ping is always great in any game, I was even playing TERA with a 21ms ping while my friend tried Guild Wars again and had the same connection/ping problems as I have (same room, same network).

Does anybody know how to improve this situation or is it an issue of the servers?

EDIT: I've chosen the european server, as I am living in Germany

Comment: Is it possible if you could maybe try to connect to a different server. Depending on where you are located and where that server is hosted, it might have a large impact on your ping

Comment: Where do I change the server? I remember that I chose Europe somewhere as I am from Germany. And I read something about changing districts, but sadly that didn't have any effect.

Comment: I am not familiar how the first instance of Guild Wars works, but I only know about starting a new user. then you set that specific user to a new server. I am assuming you dont have many hours on that character. Maybe create a new profile and then see which servers are closer, But Europe servers on the other hand should not give you that high of a latenc

Comment: That's the point, Europe should normally have the best ping and that's why I'm not sure if this would make sense /:

Comment: It's possible the server is overloaded.  You could check out what IP guild-wars is communicating with (`netstat -t`) then figure out what path the packet is taking (`tracert <ip address>`).  This will tell you where the issue is.  But regardless of where it is, the solution will likely be "switch servers"

Comment: Okay thank you, I'll try it out once I can and will report the results